# Numbering equations within chapters without using the chapter number

Tags: equations, numbering

Unfortunately, I'm running into the same problem for a couple of times now. I can't find the answer anywhere on this forum, so that is why I decided to post the question. What I am trying to do right now is to number the equations, but once I go to a new chapter (without using the "Chapter 1/2/3" title) I want the number of the equations to start again.

Hence, I want:

Chapter 1

Section 1

x (1.1.1)

y (1.1.2)

Section 2
z (1.2.1)
g (1.2.2)

Chapter 2

Section 1

r (2.1.1)

Unfortunately, when I use the numbered equations in chapter 2, I get (2.4.1) and not (2.1.1.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\title{Equations in chapters}

\author{Student NL}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{Problem 1}

\section*{Question 1}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
X = 8
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = 9
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\section*{Question 2}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
A = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B = 5
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}


\chapter*{Problem 2}

\section*{Question 1}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
C = 5
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D = 0
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\section*{Question 2}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
E = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F = 6
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

How can I change this?

Thanks in advance!

**Suppose now, as some of you suggested, I make use of the Chapter numbers. I do have another issue then. In the example below, in chapter 2, section 2 does not contain any equations, while section 3 does. In section 3, I then get 2.2.1 instead of 2.3.1. How can I avoid this?**

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fullpage}

    \title{Equations in chapters}

    \author{Student NL}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \chapter{Problem 1}

    \section{Question 1}

    \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}
    X = 8
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    y = 9
    \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}

    \section{Question 2}
    \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}
    A = 3
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    B = 5
    \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}


    \chapter{Problem 2}

    \section{Question 1}

    \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}
    C = 5
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    D = 0
    \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}

    \section{Question 2}
    \section{Question 3}
    \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}
    E = 1
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
    F = 6
    \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: it is more or less impossible to guess what your input looks like and why the equation number is not being reset, try to make a small self contained document that shows the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: I'm quite new and I'm not sure how to do this. \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{Problem 1}

\section*{Question 1}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
X = 8
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = 9
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\section*{Question 2}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
A = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B = 5
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

Comment: \chapter*{Problem 2}

\section*{Question 1}

\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
C = 5
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D = 0
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}

Comment: This is what I wrote in LaTeX

Comment: Your fragment of code gives some insight what you doing wrong (newer redefine `\theequation` in a text), however not enough that we can help you. Please, read again @DavidCarlisle comment and do what he suggest you!

Comment: do not put the code in comments add it to your question, paste it in then while highlighted use the `{}` button which will mark it as a code section with linebreaks preserved,

Comment: It is hard to answer as the input is rather strange, why are you using _unnumbered_ headings such as `\chapter*` for numbered chapters. That is basically the problem as you are disabling most of latex's support for automatic numbering

Comment: @StudentNL: Your question is badly worded, edit your question and explain better your problem so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you just want equations numbered per section rather than per chapter

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

    \title{Equations in chapters}

    \author{Student NL}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \chapter{Problem 1}

    \section{Question 1}

aaa
    \begin{equation}
    X = 8
    \end{equation}

aaa
    \begin{equation}
    y = 9
    \end{equation}

    \section{Question 2}
aaa
    \begin{equation}
    A = 3
    \end{equation}
aaa
    \begin{equation}
    B = 5
    \end{equation}


    \chapter{Problem 2}

    \section{Question 1}
aaa
    \begin{equation}
    C = 5
    \end{equation}
aaa
    \begin{equation}
    D = 0
    \end{equation}

    \section{Question 2}
    \section{Question 3}
aaa
    \begin{equation}
    E = 1
    \end{equation}
aa
    \begin{equation}
    F = 6
    \end{equation}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Voting up, since nobody else appreciates your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Note: The O.P. changed the question to another direction, but this was answered before those changes.

As far as I understand the O.P. the trouble is that `\chapter*` does not reset the equation counter (as no other counter is reset as well). This can be cured by using `\xpretocmd`.

The counter output format should be changed as a patch too, since `subequations` redefines this everytime it's called.

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{xpatch}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\xpatchcmd{\subequations}{%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
}{%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Failed!}}


\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{equation}{0}\setcounter{parentequation}{0}}{\typeout{Yes!}}{\typeout{Failed to patch \@schapter}}
\makeatother



\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Problem 1} 
\section*{Question 1}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation} 
    X = 8 
  \end{equation} 
  \begin{equation} 
    y = 9 
  \end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 
\section*{Question 2} 
\begin{subequations} 
  \begin{equation} 
    A = 3 
  \end{equation} 
  \begin{equation} 
    B = 5 
  \end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 


\chapter*{Problem 2}
\section*{Question 1} 
\begin{subequations} 
\begin{equation} 
  C = 5 
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} 
  D = 0 
\end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Here's the `\chapter` version:**

```
\documentclass{report} 

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\xpatchcmd{\subequations}{%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
}{%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
}{\typeout{Success!}}{\typeout{Failed!}}


\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{equation}{section}


\begin{document} 
\chapter{Problem 1} 
\section{Question 1}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation} 
    X = 8 
  \end{equation} 
  \begin{equation} 
    y = 9 
  \end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 
\section{Question 2} 
\begin{subequations} 
  \begin{equation} 
    A = 3 
  \end{equation} 
  \begin{equation} 
    B = 5 
  \end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 


\chapter{Problem 2}
\section{Question 1} 
\begin{subequations} 
\begin{equation} 
  C = 5 
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} 
  D = 0 
\end{equation} 
\end{subequations} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I'd rather suggest using `\chapter` and `\section` rather than using the unnumbered forms and then having to patch everything else to cope.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's true, but it's the O.P's design decision

Comment: That is indeed true, but my issue is that the document contains the answers of an exercise I have to make and therefore I would like to give the chapter different names, than Chapter 1. But having "chapter 1, and then Problem 1" below each other is a bit ugly, I would say

Comment: Suppose I change it to having the chapter numbers, it goes well, except for  the fact that if I have equations in section 1 and section 3, then in section 3 it uses 1.2.1 instead of 1.3.1 (what I want)

Comment: @StudentNL: I don't understand your complaints